# Equivalent of PHP format('%R%a.%h'); in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

What is the equivalent of this function of php in mysql:

`$cba=date_diff($cb,$ca);
 $cba->format('%R%a.%h');`

> output: Date: 1.12 //that's 1day and 12 hours

Here's where I'm going to use it for:

`DATEDIFF(q2.adate, q1.deact) AS ND,`

Can i do the same process in mysql alone, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this using [TIMEDIFF](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timediff-function.php)

```
SELECT CONCAT(
   FLOOR(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(q2.adate, q1.deact)) / 24), ' days, ',
   MOD(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(q2.adate, q1.deact)), 24), ' hours, '
)
AS ND
```

> MySQL TIMEDIFF() returns the differences between two time or datetime
>   expressions. It is to be noted that two expressions must be of same
>   type.

Comment: Sir @jameshwart lopez, This works but can i add (- or +) negative/positive signs also? TQ

Comment: base on my answer that uses MYSQL HOUR. negative signs could not be done.

Comment: @MattMagallo use `SELECT CONCAT( IF(LEFT(TIMEDIFF(q2.adate, q1.deact),1)='-','-','+'), FLOOR(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(q2.adate, q1.deact)) / 24), '.', MOD(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(q2.adate,q1.deact)), 24) ) AS ND`

Comment: @jameshwartlopez but he can use directly `TIMEDIFF`

Comment: Thank you for the help both of you sir @fusion3k and jameshwart lopez, it is not working perfectly ^_^

Answer (score 1):

From MySQL Docs:

> [DATEDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) returns expr1 − expr2 **expressed as a value in days** from one date to the other. expr1 and expr2 are date or date-and-time expressions. **Only the date parts of the values are used in the calculation.**

You can use `TIMEDIFF` instead:

> [TIMEDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) returns expr1 − expr2 **expressed as a time value.** expr1 and expr2 are time or date-and-time expressions, but both **must be of the same type.**

So the result of `TIMEDIFF` is like:

> ```
> -00:00:00.000000  // Negative times
>  00:00:00.000000  // Positive times
> ```

or `TIMESTAMPDIFF`:

> [TIMESTAMPDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) returns datetime_expr2 − datetime_expr1, where datetime_expr1 and datetime_expr2 **are date or datetime expressions.** One expression may be a date and the other a datetime; a date value is treated as a datetime having the time part '00:00:00' where necessary. The unit for **the result (an integer)** is given by the unit argument. The legal values for unit are the same as those listed in the description of the [TIMESTAMPADD()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampadd) function.

So:

> ```
> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,'2003-02-01','2003-05-01 12:05:55');
> ```

will return `128885` (minutes).

---

- See more about [MySQL Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)